# Meteor.js $ordberBy not working?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Here is the index:

```
contracts._ensureIndex({asset_type: 1, createdAt: 1});
```

Here is the query:

```
var result = contracts.find({
                        $query:{
                            asset_type: "forward Contract", 
                            createdAt: {$gte: filter.startDate, $lte: filter.endDate}
                        },
                        $hint: {
                            asset_type: 1, createdAt: 1
                        },
                        $orderBy: {
                            createdAt: -1
                        }
                    }, {
                        skip: skip,
                        limit: 10
                    }
                ).fetch()
```

The createdAt field holds timestamp. I want to get the result in descending order i.e., latests documents first.

But the orderBy doesn't seem to work?

Comment: `$orderBy` should be `$orderby`

Comment: If you're not using the native mongoDB driver, the API for Meteor mongo collection is different. The fields and order are passed as the second (`options`) argument with different keys. See the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor has a bit different implementation of MongoDB owing to its isomorphic nature. Here's how to do it :

```
var result = contracts.find({
              asset_type: "forward Contract", 
              createdAt: {$gte: filter.startDate, $lte: filter.endDate}
            },{
              sort:{createdAt: -1},
              skip: skip,
              limit: 10      
            }).fetch()
```